# Add a product to a shopping cart/favourites php

Tags: php, sql, shopping-cart

I am trying to allow users to add destinations to their favourites page, similar to adding products to a shopping cart. I am doing this by saving the destinations to a session array and then adding this session array onto the end of an SQL SELECT statment to print the destinations. Although the code I have written only allows me to add one destination to favourites. Can anyone point my in the right direction.

```
if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
} else {
    array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['theid']);
    // HOW TO LOOP THROUGH SESSION CART

    $str =  implode(',', $_SESSION['cart']) ;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Destinations WHERE DestID IN ($str)" ;

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        echo $row['DestName'].' '.$row['DestRating'].
             ' <img src="Images/'.$row['DestImage'].'" /> <br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: If we suppose `$_SESSION['cart']` is an array then you can loop through it like this `foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $currentSession){ // code here }`

Comment: Why do you think _the code I have only allows me to add one destination to favourites_ It looks like you can add as many as you like. So what error are you getting when you add more than one